# Unable to insert into MySQL using Perl

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm new to Perl and I have been trying this simple program to insert values into a database. I have two files, an HTML file that sends the form values to the Perl file. But I'm not able to perform any insertion or retrieval; I always get an empty page as the output.

HTML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>8th program</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://localhost:81/cgi-bin/8.pl" method="post">
            NAME:<input type="text" name="name"><br>
            AGE:<input type="text" name="age"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Perl file:

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

print "Content-Type:text/html\n\n";

use CGI ':standard';
use DBI;

print "<html><head><title>insert</title></head>";

$dbh  = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:test", "root", " " );

$name = param( "name" );
$age  = param( "age" );

$qh   = $dbh->prepare( "insert into student values('$name','$age')" );
$qh->execute();

$qh = $dbh->prepare( "select * from student" );
$qh->execute();

print "<table border size=1>
       <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       </tr>";

while ( ( $name, $age ) = $qh->fetchrow() ) {
    print "<tr><td>$name</td>
 <td>$age</td></tr>";
}

print "</table>";

$qh->finish();

$dbh->disconnect();

print "</html>";
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: The error message thrown by Perl very specifically identifies the problem.

Comment: (1) What error message(s) do you get? You should be able to find them in your web server's error log. (2) Interpolating values from the web form directly into your SQL string is a HUGE security hole. Use SQL placeholders instead. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for more details about both the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: **Danger**: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use placeholders in your prepared statements.

Comment: @Quentin: That has been covered in the comment from *Dave Sherohman*, and in my solution

Answer (score 4):

There is no DBI method `fetchrow`. In this instance it looks like you mean `fetchrow_array`

In addition, please take note of these points

- On Windows systems, a shebang line is ignored except that any command switches specified there will be honoured. The path to the perl compiler / interpreter must be defined elsewhere
- You *must always*

  ```
  use strict;
  use warnings 'all';
  ```

  at the top of every Perl program you write, and declare every variable as close as possible to its first point of use
- You should use *placeholders* instead of interpolating parameters into SQL strings. Like this, for example

  ```
  my $qh = $dbh->prepare( 'INSERT INTO student (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)' );
  $qh->execute($name, $age);
  ```
- It is wrong to call `finish`. [The documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#finish) has this

  > Adding calls to "finish" after [a] loop that fetches all rows is a common
  >   mistake, don't do it, it can mask genuine problems like uncaught fetch
  >   errors.